# Connecting a Docker container running PHP to the host's(ubuntu on VirtualBox) MSQL server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, docker-container

Running VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04 on which I have a Docker container that has Apache2 and PHP installed.

MYSQL is installed on the host(ubuntu on VirtualBox).

I am trying to access the MYSQL server on host from the docker container

```
<?php
$host = '192.168.136.101';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '****';
$db = 'test';
$port = '3306';

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db,$port);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

?>

I get a connection refused notice.

when starting the container I have tried

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 -p 3306:3306 IMAGE
```

Which doesn't work as port 3306 is being used by MYSQL server on host and if I stop MYSQL server on host the docker run command executes however I am then unable to start MYSQL service on host

I have also tried

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 --add-host=database:192.168.136.101 IMAGE
```

and changed the bind address in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf accordingly

still no luck

Thanks

Comment: Below post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the host network when running your container :

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 --net="host" IMAGE
```

Then, you can reference your database with localhost :

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '****';
$db = 'test';
$port = '3306';
```

You can also use the --net="bridge" option, which the default, instead of "host", but in that case you need to find out your host's IP, and configure Mysql to listen to the container's ip in the file my.cnf :

```
bind-address = x.y.z.u
```

where x.y.z.u is your container's IP.

Comment: when binding the container IP address to my.cnf's bind address MYSQL server does not start giving the error notice
'Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details'

Comment: Sorry it does work!

From host enter
     sudo ip addr show docker0

Comment: Whereas before I was using the IP address obtained from ifconfig when run from container